# making a new char* out of two old char*s

Tags: c++, c, char, concatenation

I am open to using intermediary C++ code, though C code is the preference.

I have code like the following:

```
char *fileName1 = "graph";
char *extension1 = ".eps";
```

I want to create a new `char*` variable called `fileName1WithExtension1` which would correspond to "graph.eps", formed from the two `char*` variables given above. How can this be done?

Comment: Consider using `std::string` instead

Comment: For straight up C try `strcat()`

Comment: Don't use `char *` with string literals. They're not modifiable.

Comment: @chris I would generally agree, but I do have to say that immutability can sometimes be useful. For instance, Java String objects are immutable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use C++, have those as [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) strings:

```
std::string fileName1 = "graph";
std::string extension1 = ".eps";
```

And then simply

```
std::string fileName1WithExtension1 = filename1 + extension1;
```

If you then need to pass that to a C library function expecting a C string, get char pointer with `fileName1WithExtension1.c_str()`

There really is no reason to muck about with plain C strings in C++ code. It is so error-prone and tedious, that it should be actively avoided.

Answer (score 4):

```
char *new_string;

new_string = malloc(strlen(fileName1) + strlen(extension1) + 1);
sprintf(new_string, "%s%s", fileName1, extension1);

...

free(new_string)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `asprintf()` function

```
char *buffer;
asprintf (&buffer, "%s%s", fileName1, extension1);
```

When the `buffer` variable become useless in your code, you have to free the memory allocated for buffer by asprintf  with

```
free(buffer);
```

Comment: Note that `asprintf` is GNU extension, not in any standard: http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf

Answer (score 2):

```
char *joined;
joined = (char*)malloc(strlen(fileName1) + strlen(extension1) + 1);
strcpy(joined, fileName1)
strcat(joined, extension1)
```

For a small performance increase, if the compiler is smart enough at optimizing, change the last line to

```
strcpy(joined+strlen(fileName1), extension1)
```

Even better, store the length of fileName1 in a variable the first time you determine it, and use it in the final strcpy().

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go REALLY low-level, with ugly loops and such, you can do this: (Tested, it compiles and gives the expected and desired results)

```
char* filename1 = "graph";
char* extension1 = ".eps";
char* filename1WithExtension1 = combine(filename1, extension1);
```

where:

```
char* combine(char* str1, char* str2)
{
    int str1len = 0, str2len = 0;
    while(str1[str1len] != '\0') {
        str1len++;
    }
    while(str2[str2len] != '\0') {
        str2len++;
    }
    int outputlen = str1len + str2len + 1;
    char* output = new char[outputlen];
    for(int i = 0; i < str1len; i++)
    {
        output[i] = str1[i];
    }
    for(int i = str1len; i < outputlen; i++)
    {
        output[i] = str2[i - str1len];
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Why not use `strcpy` and `strcat`?  They are already written and tested.  See the C string library.  See answer by DarenW.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews One reason to not use `strcpy`/`strcat` is, they do not return end of string in any way, which is often inconvenient. But above does not take advantage of this, but instead iterates over both strings twice, so yeah...

Answer (score 1):

I did a bit of C brush-up for fun, here's an alternative (C90 and C++ compatible code) for joining an array of C strings with separator. It should be very efficient with any decently optimizing compiler, too:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* **parts are strings to join, a NULL-terminated array of char*
 * sep is separator string, use "" for no separator, must not be NULL
 * returns malloc-allocated buffer which must be freed
 * if len_out!=NULL, sets *len_out to strlen of result string */
char *astrjoin(int *len_out, const char *sep, char **parts) {

    int part_count;
    int parts_total_len = 0;

    for(part_count = 0; parts[part_count]; ++part_count) {
        parts_total_len += strlen(parts[part_count]);
    }
    if (part_count > 0) {
        int malloc_size = (part_count - 1) * strlen(sep) + parts_total_len + 1;
        char *result = (char*)malloc(malloc_size);
        char *dest = result;   
        for(;;) {
            const char *src;
            for(src=*parts; *src; ++src) *dest++ = *src;
            if (!*++parts) break;
            for(src=sep ; *src; ++src) *dest++ = *src;
        }
        *dest = 0;
        if (len_out) *len_out = malloc_size - 1;
        return result;
    } else {
        if (len_out) *len_out = 0;
        return strdup("");
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    /* argv is NULL-terminated array of char pointers */
    char *commandline = astrjoin(NULL, " ", argv);
    printf("argc: %d\nargv: %s\n", argc, commandline);
    free(commandline);
    return 0;
}
```

To call that in context of your question, it could be something like:

```
char *tmparr[] = { fileName1, exteansion1, NULL };
char *fileName1WithExtension1 = astrjoin(NULL, "", tmparr);
```

---

It would be trivial to create a version with `sep` and/or `len_out` dropped, or a version supporting "varargs", with signature looking something like:

```
char *astrjoin_va(int *len_out, const char *sep, ...);
```

Which would be nicer to call in context of your question:

```
char *fileName1WithExtension1 = astrjoin_va(NULL, "", fileName1, extension1, NULL);
```